# simple ajax click anchor not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my script

```
   <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a.exe").click(function()
    {

   e.preventDefault();



     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: this.href,
            cache:false,
            success: function(data){
                      $("#result2").append(data);
            }
     });
     return false;
}); 
});
</script>
```

my echo statement

```
  echo "<tr><td style='border:1px; width: 200px;height:30px;'>
  <a   href='http://exe.net/free/action1.php?id1=".$id1."' 
                                         class='exe' >".$name1."</a></td></tr>";
```

There is no ajax request...there in no value passing.. it goes straight to the url..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to pass `event` inside of `click` event function argument.

**Example**

```
$('a.exe').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); })
```

Comment: @user2234992 have you checked it in firebug..?

Answer (score 0):

Pass `e` to your `click` function:

```
$("a.exe").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
```